# Can't paste Java source file into IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: file, intellij-idea, copy-paste

I recently moved to IntelliJ IDEA. 
And I need to add several files to one of the packages in my project.

The problem is I couldn't paste these files into that package. I also tried pasting the files in Explorer and pressing F5 in IntelliJ IDEA, but it did not work.

How to copy the files into IntelliJ except manually creating these source files one by one?

Comment: After pasting the files in explorer and restart intellij idea, these files appeared. But how to do this without restarting the intellij idea?

Comment: Which version?  On what OS?  Just curious, because I haven't seen that problem on IntelliJ 7.0.5 running on Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason there's now two or three different paste functions available from the drop-down menu. One of them usually works. There's also a *synchronize* button under the file menu which may be used when there's inconsistencies , but frankly I very seldom use the synchronize button.

I have no idea why there's so many different paste functions, and it's definitely not very nice in an IDE that is known for its general niceness ;)

Comment: Though it's not a good idea, thank you all the same.
At least, you reminded me the synchronize button. :)

Answer (score 0):

copy one-to-one files to destination in intellj.Several selected files don't work.